# Why subprocess gives Error: output could not be opened

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix, subprocess, popen

**Objective**

This Python program writes 97 unix commands to 97 separate lists to be processed with the subprocess Popen/run function.

The unix commands written call an application, commands for the application, and in/out files the application needs to run.

The program checks for whether or not a filename is in a global list, and if not, runs the program with subprocess.Popen([each of the 97 unix commmands]), and inserts the file name into the list.

```
import subprocess
import time
import sys 
import os

def readFilenames(sent_directory):

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sent_directory, topdown=False):
        for name in files:
            currentFilePath = (os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, name)))
            currentFileName = (os.path.join(root, name))[21:-5]

            scriptEx(currentFilePath, currentFileName)



def scriptEx(path, name):

    global idxlist

    idx = name + 'idx'
    args = (['application', '[CMD]', '[CMD]', idx, path])


    process(idx, args, idxlist)


def process(idx, args, idxlist):

    if idx in idxlist:
        return

    else:
        subprocess.Popen(args)
        idxlist.append(idx)
        time.sleep(400)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    directory_name=sys.argv[0]

    try:
        directory_name=sys.argv[1]

    except:
        print('\nPlease pass directory name\n\n')

    idxlist = []
    readFilenames(directory_name)
```

**Output**

Among the output printed to the screen in real time from the application, there is a line I do not encounter when running the commands singly.

```
Error: index output file could not be opened!
```

There are no output files from the application as there should be when I run this Python program.

**Failed Solutions**

I have found one source mentioning this specific error. The only reply was asking OP if he/she could `touch input_file`.

Thinking it was a permissions problem, I chmod 777 everything to no avail, and `touch all_input_files`.

Also, I have tried `subprocess.call`, `subprocess.run`, and `subprocess.check_output`.

Comment: Which line had the problem? Can you post the full stack trace so we can see what happened?

Comment: `POpen` does not wait for the command to complete then you sleep 400 seconds, presumably to make up for that. You could `subprocess.check_call(args)` which waits for the command to complete and raises an exception on non-zero return code. The error is coming from the app and there is no way we'd know what that means. It seems strange, though, that you don't pass the full file name (`currentFileName = (os.path.join(root, name))[21:-5]`) or check to see if its really a file you want to process. Add `print(args)` right before the call to `check_call` and run that manually.

Comment: How does the app know where its supposed to write files?

Comment: I reasoned to sleep 400s to be courteous about how many processes I run at a time on the shared cluster. Another approach I had was to send a process only if the number of processes with the application name were under a certain number. I reasoned that the application would not need the full file name since it didn't when running one instance at a time. The application deposited output in the directory it was called from. I wanted to check if its really a file I wanted to process, but have not really thought through how to check.